# How to append custom code to the generated service worker file

Tags: webpack, sw-precache

I'm using Webpack and swPrecache. swPrecache generates a service-worker.js file for me and I now want to append custom code to the generated file.

I created a Webpack plugin that appends the babel transformed code to the service-worker.js file, like so:

```
swPrecache.write(filePath, options, (function(err) {

  // If we want to append an additional file.
  if (options.appendFile) {
    var sync = fs.readFile(options.appendFile, (error, code) => {
      if (error) {
        throw error;
      }
      let transformed = babel.transform(code, options.babelConfig || {});
      fs.appendFile(filePath, transformed.code);
    });
  }

  callback(err);
}));
```

This however does not include the code to make `require()` work in the file i'm appending. I believe I need to use Webpack to generate the service-worker.js file but i'm unsure how to do that, possibly via a custom entry point?

Answer (score 2):

To include your custom script into generated serviceWorker, [recommended](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache/#templatefilepath-string) way is to use the `importScripts` option in `sw-precache` config.You can find more details [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache/#importscripts-arraystring).